# How to sort two columns of numbers to minimize the differences between them?

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting, optimize

I'm sorting two columns of numbers.  One is a series of spools of wire, and another is a series of needed lengths.  I want to optimize the selection of spools for the needed lengths, while flagging spools that are greater than +/- 10% different for return.  The -10% accounts for 10% overage in the "needed length" column.

In other words, I want to optimize this list to pair numbers in "original Length," which is what I have in stock, to numbers in "Revised Length," which are the needed lengths, in order to minimize the differences between them, and then flag differences that are out of the 10% range.  I also need to keep track of the Reel # in order to flag spools for return.

Any ideas on how to efficiently accomplish this?

Here's an example of the data I'm working with:

[Wire Length Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSHNA.png)

[image]

Comment: Hi @Matt could you please share some sample data with us to justify the method we apply ! And what do mean by discarding,,, are U thinking to keep those values out of  SORT?

Comment: *Here's an example of the data I'm working with:* Show desired result for this source data.

Answer (score 0):

We have 2 columns of lengths in columns A and B on the worksheet with the name "Sheet1" (this is random-generated values in the ranges from 100 to 1000).

[image]

We open VBA editor (Alt-F11) and add common module (Insert - Module). Into this module we insert the below code:

```vba
Sub SetPairs()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer, len1 As Integer, len2 As Integer
Const Difference As Single = 0.1 ' 10% '

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
With sh.Sort
    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
    .SetRange Range("A:A")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
    .SetRange Range("B:B")
    .Apply
End With
i = 2
Do
    len1 = sh.Cells(i, 1).Value
    len2 = sh.Cells(i, 2).Value
    If 1# * len1 * len2 = 0 Then Exit Do
    If Abs(len1 - len2) / (len1 + len2) > Difference / 2 Then
        If len1 > len2 Then
            Cells(i, 1).Insert xlShiftDown
        Else
            Cells(i, 2).Insert xlShiftDown
        End If
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Then we execute this code and obtain the next result:

[image]

The pairs which differs less than 10% are posessed in the same row, the values which have no matched paired value stays alone.

PS. 10% is approximate - I use the formula (abs of difference is less then 5% of sum). You may alter it freely.

Comment: Hey @Akina ,, this code is working but,, the OP want to *while discarding spools that are greater than +/- 10% different.* and this code includes all values from both Columns !!

Comment: @RajeshS The spools which differs more than 10% (and so must be discarded) stays alone in a row (have no matched trace). "Discard" is not necessarily "delete".

Comment: Not sure exactly what he is asking, but I would quibble with his `+/- 10%` specification. Unless he is planning to splice wires together, it might be better expressed as `+10%/-0%`

Comment: @Akina,, the sample data posted by OP is different than yours,,, just check the link above !!

Comment: @RajeshS This source data was added later that I have posted this answer. If OP'd post the desired result I'd edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Akina,,, I think the  method should apply on Data shared by OP,, and result to your's & #Ron Rosenfeld are different !!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you want.

But perhaps:

- Sort the Original along with the REEL #
- Sort the Revised
- Compute the %Diff
- Flag those outside of +/- 10% length diff

If so, you can do this with formulas if you have O365/Excel with the latest `SORT` function, along with Conditional Formatting.

If you don't have the `SORT` function, you can easily set up a Query in `Power Query` to accomplish the same thing, or even do it manually with the `Data Sort` option in Excel.

See below:

```
F3: =SORT(A2:B11,2)
H3: =SORT(C2:C11)
I3: =1-(H3/G3) (and fill down)
```

Then select the resulting table data `F3:I12`

Conditional format with a formula:  `=ABS($I3) > 0.1`

[image]

**NOTE:**

- This method will not provide optimal answers

  - If there are different numbers of desired lengths than actual lengths
  - It you might want to combine several desired lengths to "add-up" to a single reel length.

If you need to truly optimize, you will need a VBA solution.

Comment: Hi @Ron Rosenfeld,, what you have suggested can be achieve by using the usual SORT command,,, on 1st Original then 2nd on Revised length,,, in Ascending order and apply CF. As OP written originally that after SORT value difference +/- 10% should be separated (modified recently) for that along with SORT the Filter can be used for Off 365.